# Erro ao buscar lista no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com um problema no meu sistema de enviar emails newsletter, ao carregar a index, onde são carregados a lista de emails cadastrados, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean   given in /home/barie742/public_html/admin/admin/index.php on line 284
```

Na linha 284 está assim:

```
  <?php
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_emails order by -id");
  while($lista2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  /* line 284 */
  $email = $lista2["email"];
  $ativo = $lista2["ativo"];
```

O que pode estar errado ?
E como posso arrumar ?

Agradeço a todos que tentarem ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que é que poderás estar a usar a $resultado dentro desse while para fazer alguma coisa tornando-o falso

```
         <?php
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_emails order by -id");
      $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      while($lista2=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
          $email = $lista2["email"];
          $ativo = $lista2["ativo"];
      }
```

Comment: Tirou o erro porém agora está aparecendo: Query was empty

Comment: Pronto, está ai o teu problema, a query não está a devolver nada dai o $resultado ser false (bool)

Comment: Então meu erro é mais profundo? Tem emails cadastrados e não aparece, erro na conexão com banco de dados?

Comment: Poderá ser algo na tua query, terás que ver melhor o que estás a ir buscar e onde estás a buscar, se a minha resposta te resolveu o problema marca como respondido :)

Comment: obrigado a ajuda amigo, problema resolvido